# Stuck with H77 (non-OC) and I5-2500K

Tags: gaming, processor, desktop, motherboard

The i5-2500K is a great processor, even nowadays, but only if you can overclock it. I have a H77 chipset board, that means no OC for me. So, I need a recommendation of CPU and motherboard. I'm looking for a "successor", good cost/benefit, like the 2500k. 
I have DDR3 RAM, so I think Skylake is a problem?

PC specs:

- CPU: i5-2500K turbo: 3.7GHz
- Motherboard: Asus P8H77-V LE
- RAM: 4x4GB DDR3 1333mhz (dual channel only, 1.5V)
- GPU: Nvidia GTX950

Comment: What's your price range? What's wattage can your power supply handle? Do you have brand preferences (CPU or mobo)? What form factor do you have/want? What kind of games do you expect to be playing? More importantly, what's your price range?

Comment: I live in Brazil, so price range is a complicated subject. 500w power supply. ATX/MicroATX. I expect to be playing games like GTA V and newer titles for a good time, just like the old processor. My price range would be about 1200BRL, or about 300-425 US$. Please suggest more than one model, so that I can search what is available here. Thank you.

Comment: What's your bottleneck? I have a system that's roughly of similar vintage, tho core i7 and z series motherboard and it holds up well.

Comment: Are you sure the problem is CPU? You might consider looking at the GTX 1080, which, I believe, should be in that price range and is really powerful. Usually, up to a certain point, CPU + RAM aren't the main limiters in game performance.

Comment: Bottleneck is definitely CPU. It's a 2011 CPU not overclocked. A GTX 1080 here will be priced about 1k $. Journey, you have a i7 and a overclockable chipset, but I've seen my cpu on games, and it is 100% all the time. The price range is for a mobo+cpu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest going to Skylake.  However, I don't know what kind of prices you'll pay for it, but I'll throw some things our there and you can decide how to proceed.

Motherboard, one option @ ~$98 **Gigabyte GA-Z170-HD3 ATX LGA1151**

Processor, @ ~$195 **Intel Core i5-6500 3.2GHz Quad-Core** (you could bump down to 6400 or an i3-6100 for good performance/price)

RAM, you will have to have DDR4, @ ~$35 **G.Skill Ripjaws V Series 8GB (2 x 4GB) DDR4-2400**

This is what I'm considering for a modest upgrade for myself.  I also used this, http://www.logicalincrements.com/# to help me make some recommendations along with http://pcpartpicker.com/ to look at similar parts and prices.  Both sites are great tools.

Comment: Mobo only $250 US here. But thanks for the help. Will consider Skylake. Thanks for site recommendations.

Comment: You could look at other 1151 socket boards.  I've not really looked into any previous generation Intel, and when I did the prices weren't much different, for me anyway.  That's why I recommended Skylake.  I suppose you could look at used, if there is any options for you to use and look into the previous gen stuff.